# Truncate Text using ellipsis keeping the caret always at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make this button text to truncate without hiding the caret.

When text is long it hides the caret.
I want to keep the caret at the end and truncate the text only.

This is my code

     Sample Text

```css
.btn-default {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    max-width: 16em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button id="L1.900Level" class="btn btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle btn-xl-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"><span> short text </span><span class="caret"></span></button>

<button id="L1.900Level" class="btn btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle btn-xl-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"><span> loooooooooooooooooooooooong text </span><span class="caret"></span></button>
```

Comment: What you have tried for this ? Share your code here.

Comment: @MadanBhandari shared the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@NOTE** this solution is for bootstrap 4 where icon is not added by .caret but from :after selector nonetheless same logic may work on older versions as well. 
For this to work you need an additional `span` tag.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn w-100 dropdown-toggle">
    <span>Alle Termine</span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-toggle {
    span {
           white-space: nowrap;
           text-overflow: ellipsis;
           overflow: hidden;
           display: inline-block;
           max-width: calc(100% - 5px); // prevents icon from touching right border
           vertical-align: middle;
     }
}
```

Notice button should have a certain width. In my case button gets 100% width of the parent container but you may have another width in your case.

This worked well on my end. I hope it helps other people as well!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by giving position absolute to the caret element and place end of your button

```
.btn-default span.caret {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

And you should make the parent element position as relative

```
.btn-default {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    max-width: 16em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    position: relative:
}
```